# debugging of OCX through Delphi

Tags: delphi, debugging, ocx

Hello I am having one delphi application which have the output file extension ABC.ocx. Now this ABC.ocx is used to copy some data from server machine to local machine. This ABC.ocx is called from another application/dll. Is there any way to debug this? How can i set the breakpoint in delphi when I click on another application/dll which executes ABC.ocx. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the calling application as the host application.

Another pitfall is that the ocx may be copied to another location before it is loaded, in which case, you should set your project's output path to that location as well.

The steps needed are explained in detail here:
http://www.drbob42.com/activex/debugx.htm

Comment: is there any way to know location where the ocx will get copied?

Comment: For most applications, I assume this behaviour is documented, but you may use a tool like Process Explorer to see which libraries are loaded by a process and from what location. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: found one ABC.ocx at location in the C:\WINNT\Donloaded Program Files\abc.cab

Comment: ABC.ocx is a part of abc.cab. In this case what path should i specify in out directory?

Comment: I doubt that the ocx is loaded directly from the cab. Have you tried process explorer?

Comment: yes i tried process Explorer and searched for abc.ocx. Its showing the location C:\WINNT\Donloaded Program Files\abc.ocx.

Comment: I have done following steps: 1. Attached the Internet Explorer.exe to process. 2. Chnaged the output directory to C:\WINNT\Donloaded Program Files. Now when i run the appication then internet explorer will open but when i click on the link which calls abc.ocx it will not go to that breakpoint which i set in delphi. Am i missing any other settings??